# How to send json data to codeigniter view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi i have a question based on how i am going to replace my web page section with the returned data from my controller. I have a page that displays the details of the movies directly from my database and i want when a user selects a specific genre then only the movies of that certain category wil be displayed. I have managed to get the name of each genre from the select box and send it to the controller were i will use it to extract the data from the database. In my html i am using a foreach loop to load **ALL** the data and my problem is how i will display them back to the view and manipulate my php/html code in order to display them(actually replace the existing php/html with the new as an ajax request).  I know i have to use json_encode() to send them back as an object but i don't know how to display them or iterate the data in the php/html tags.

Javascript

```
$(".select__sort").change(function()
    {

        var genre = $(".select__sort").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/Cinema_Seat_Booking_System/movie_list_full/order_by_genre",
            data: {'cat':genre},
            dataType:"json",
            cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }
      });
    });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="select-area">

                <form class="select select--film-category" method='get'>
                      <select name="select_item" class="select__sort" tabindex="0">
                        <option value="default" selected="selected">All</option>
                          <?php foreach($genres as $category): ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $category->genre ?>" selected="selected"> <?php echo $category->genre ?></option>
                          <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </form>

        </div>
```

HTML foreach loop movie data

```
<!-- Movie preview item -->
            <?php foreach($movies_data as $movie_data) :?>
            <div class="movie movie--preview movie--full release">
                 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="movie__images">
                            <img alt='' src=<?php echo $movie_data->path ?>>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 movie__about">
                        <a href='view_movie_page_full.php' class="movie__title link--huge"><?php echo $movie_data->title ?></a>

                        <p class="movie__time"><?php echo $movie_data->duration_min ?></p>

                        <p class="movie__option"><strong>Country: </strong><a href="#"><?php echo $movie_data->country ?></a href="#"></p>
                        <p class="movie__option"><strong>Category: </strong><a href="#"><?php echo $movie_data->genre ?></a></p>
                        <p class="movie__option"><strong>Director: </strong><a href="#"><?php echo $movie_data->director ?></a></p>
                        <p class="movie__option"><strong>Actors: </strong><a href="#"><?php echo $movie_data->actors ?></a></p>

                        <div class="movie__btns">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('book1')?>" class="btn btn-md btn--warning">book a ticket <span class="hidden-sm">for this movie</span></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="preview-footer">
                            <div class="movie__rate"><div class="score"></div><span class="movie__rate-number"></span> </div>


                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>



            </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <!-- end movie preview item -->
```

Controller

```
 public function order_by_genre()
{
    $this->load->model('movie_list_full_model');

    $ajax_request = $this->input->post('cat');
    $query_data['genres'] = $this->movie_list_full_model->get_all_genres($ajax_request);


    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('home/view_movie_list_full', $query_data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer_movie_list_full');

}
```

ps I want the page to change the data with out reloading it, that's the reason i am trying it with ajax but i am fairly new to this and i am stuck. Any help?

Comment: One place to start might be to take a look at what the AJAX request is asking for, and what your controller is sending back. From the looks of it, your AJAX is expecting some json to come back, but you're loading templates which I'm assuming are php/html views? If that's the case, you might have better luck using $.load() and just dropping the returned information into a div on your initial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if ajax used post to get to your controller and then return json encode

```
public function order_by_genre(){

$this->load->model('movie_list_full_model');
$is_post = $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST';

if($is_post){
     $ajax_request = $this->input->post('cat');

     echo json_encode( $this->movie_list_full_model->get_all_genres($ajax_request));
  }
else {
      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('home/view_movie_list_full', $query_data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer_movie_list_full');
     }
}
```

And then in javascript you can use $(this).val() it gets the value of changed element ( you can use this a lot ) and then if ajax call is success in div where you show your movies just append every movie with forEach loop

```
$(".select__sort").change(function()
{

    var genre = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/Cinema_Seat_Booking_System/movie_list_full/order_by_genre",
        data: {'cat':genre},
        dataType:"json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          $("#movies").html(" "); //clear everything from movie div

            data.forEach(function(entry) {   
             $("#movies").append("<div>"+entry.movie+"</div>");
               //just add everything here
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where you say //just add everything here what exactly do you mean? What things should i add. Note that i edited my post and added the part of the foreach loop for the movies data in order to understand whati have done

Comment: That part that you edited right now in that foreach loop, you clear that div and appand all movies inside of forEach in ajax success,you go like this `$(".movie__about").append("<a href='view_movie_page_full.php' class='movie__title link--huge'>"+entry.title+"</a>");` and just add everything like that

Comment: Ok i got it thanks. But i am running to another problem prior to that. When i extract the data and send it back as a json it returns null on the log console or when i use alert to check them but when i test the scenario if the data are not returning from the controller i find that they are still returning normally as it displays the data in a test page which i use. I research the problem and i think is something with the codeigniter returning array from query and the json_encoding. Any ideas?

Comment: change return to echo or print, inside of controller, I edited that.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience one final question regarding clearing the div. First if i clear the div(movie) then i cannot add the data as it can't find the appropriate lets say image div(movie__images) as everything is cleared and second if i try to clear not the whole div but the image div then the foreach loop of html keeps looping and prints the json data by its length. I am confuse with that

Comment: You can add div before foreach loop in php and then instead of clearing that div just add `$('yourdivhere').html("<div class='movie movie--preview movie--full release'><div class='col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2'><div class='movie__images'></div></div>");` this will clear the div and add movie movie--preview with movie___images to it, and you can do it like that