# How to get Codeigniter api response from controller to get in view page using Jquery

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I have Form below,

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('api/v1/controller/function/format/json')?>" method="post" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="edit_form">
```

And below is my controller response,

```
{"response":"error","msg":{"value":"some data"}}
```

How can I get above message value in view page using Jquery, During ajax call we use data method to get response but in form submit case how can I get ?..
Any Help is appreciated

Comment: This would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137365/how-to-send-json-data-to-codeigniter-view

Comment: little bit helpfull, Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access json object using this method.

```js
var obj = {"response":"error","msg":{"value":"some data"}};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = obj.msg.value;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


</body>
</html>
```